# R : How to search for a regex in a vector over elements outwardly?

Tags: regex, r

Is it possible in R to search for a regex in a vector as if all the elements are a collapsed single element? If we collapse all the elements into one to do this, it becomes impossible to put them back to their element-wise form after the search.

here is a vector.

```
vector<-c("I", "met", "a", "cow")
```

now, the search word is "meta" (elements 2 and 3 collapsed).

Let's say my task is to merge the two elements across which the search string lies.

So what I expect is this:

```
vector = "I", "meta", "cow"
```

Is it possible to do this? Please help.

Comment: For clarification, you want to: first, search for whether the string is present, and second, return a new vector with the merged string. Is this correct?

Comment: Also, will the search always be across two or more *complete* strings from the source? That is to say, you'll not be searching for "taco" (which can be found starting at the last letter of "met")?

Comment: @mrdwab makes a good point: if you want to find "taco" then you'll have "leftover" strings and you haven't said what you'd do with them. So, if you only want to fit complete strings, then rather than collapsing the entire list, just collapse in pairs, e.g.  `paste(vector[j],vector[j+1],collapse='')` and do regexp on that.  In fact, if you want the result of "taco" to be "metacow", a slight modification of the results vector will still do what you want.

Comment: @mrdwab Sorry I didn't mention this, The search is always across complete strings. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you'd like something that matches `"meta"` but not `"taco"`, this will do the trick:

```
myFun <- function(vector, word) {
    D <- "UnLiKeLyStRiNg" 

    ## Construct a string on which you'll perform regex-search
    xx <- paste0(paste0(D, vector, collapse=""), D)

    ## Construct the regex pattern
    start <- paste0("(?<=", D, ")")
    mid <- paste0(strsplit(word, "")[[1]], collapse=paste0("(", D, ")?"))
    end <- paste0("(?=", D, ")")
    pat <- paste0(start, mid, end)

    ## Use it
    strsplit(gsub(pat, word, xx, perl=TRUE), D)[[1]][-1]
}

vector <- c("I", "met", "a", "cow")

myFun(vector, "meta")
# [1] "I"    "meta" "cow" 
myFun(vector, "taco")
# [1] "I"   "met" "a"   "cow"
myFun(vector, "Imet")
# [1] "Imet" "a"    "cow" 
myFun(vector, "Ime")
# [1] "I"   "met" "a"   "cow"
```

Comment: Thanks for helping again, Josh. Got what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

If only complete elements should merged, you could try this approach:

```
mergeRegExpr <- function(x, pattern) {
    str <- paste(x, sep="", collapse="")

    ## find starting position of each word
    wordStart <- head(cumsum(c(1, nchar(x))), -1)

    ## look for pattern
    rx <- regexpr(pattern=pattern, text=str, fixed=TRUE)

    ## pos of matching pattern == rx+nchar(pattern)-1
    rxEnd <- rx+attr(rx, "match.length")-1

    ## which vector elements doesn't match pattern
    sel <- wordStart < rx | wordStart > rxEnd

    ## insert merged elements
    return(append(x[sel], paste(x[!sel], collapse=""), rx-1))
}

vector <- c("I", "met", "a", "cow")

mergeRegExpr(vector, "meta")
# "I"    "meta" "cow"
mergeRegExpr(vector, "acow")
# "I"    "met"  "acow"
mergeRegExpr(vector, "Imeta")
# "Imeta" "cow"

## partial matching doesn't work    
mergeRegExpr(vector, "taco")
# "I"       "metacow"
```

Comment: Clearly partial matching does work because "I metacow" is an awesome sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Carl Witthoft's comment, my solution was not with regex, but with basic matching:

```
# A slightly longer vector
v = c("I", "met", "a", "cow", "today",
      "You", "met", "a", "cow", "today")

# Create the combinations of each pair
temp1 = sapply(1:(length(v)-1), 
               function(x) paste0(v[x], v[x+1]))

# Grab the index of the desired search term
temp2 = which(temp1 %in% "meta")
# The following also works.
# Don't know what's faster/better.
# temp2 = grep("meta", temp1)

# Do some manual substitution and deletion
v[temp2] <- "meta"
v <- v[-(temp2+1)]
```

I don't think this is an ideal situation at all though.